# string comparison with slashes in shellscript

Tags: shell

I defined a function in bash shell to search through an array of strings and determine if the input string exists.
It doesn't work on strings with slashes. Please see the code below:

```
#!/bin/bash
in_array(){
    search_path="$1"
    shift

    while [ -n "${1+defined}" ]
    do
        echo $1 $search_path
        if [ $1 = $search_path ]
        then
            return 0
        fi
        shift
    done
    return 1
}

exclude_dirs=( '/home/backup' '/home/xxx' )
in_array 'home/backup' ${exclude_dirs[@]}
echo $?
```

Can you explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are missing a slash. should be

```
in_array '/home/backup' ${exclude_dirs[@]}
```

you already had this: `echo $1 $search_path` in your code. It should show you clearly where you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are missing the initial slash in the first argument to your test case:

```
home/backup
```

vs

```
/home/backup
```