# Compare string variable with slashes in shell script

Tags: shell

In a shell script that I need to run in Jenkins, I have this portion:

```
if [ "$GIT_BRANCH" == "origin/master" ]; then
    // some fantastic stuff
else
    // some wonderful stuff
fi
```

The problem is that the strings contain a slash. So I get this error:

```
origin/master: unexpected operator
```

I've been trying string replacements for the last hour but I didn't manage to find the solution. Does anyone have a clue? Thank you.

Note: there's a question with a very similar title, but I've had a look and it's really not the same problem: [string comparison with slashes in shellscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798454/string-comparison-with-slashes-in-shellscript)

Comment: Eh? There's nothing special about slashes in comparisons. I assure you that the actual problem is something else.

Comment: For example -- what's your shell? If it's `/bin/sh`, then you should be using `=` rather than `==`. (Actually, you should probably be doing that regardless, just to avoid building finger memory that's only compatible with extended shells, as opposed to those only providing [baseline POSIX `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)).

Comment: (I'd suggest running `bash -x yourscript`, or `sh -x yourscript` as appropriate to match the interpreter you're running with in production, to log each command before it's run; the results are likely to be enlightening).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you were right. Using a single equal sign fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: (BTW, one of the hints here is the word "operator" -- the things being compared are not operators but *operands*).

Comment: Alright, I learnt 2 things in 1 (I'm not a native English speaker) :)